# Trying to get transacation details for FinalExecutionOutcome after calling changemethods on near

Tags: nearprotocol

I do have a smart contract that has both viewMethods as well as changeMethods.

I am able to deploy the contract and we are able to successfully call both the viewmethods as well as chnagementhods.

As per near documentation whenever a function is called it return the promise.
async functionCall(contractId: string, methodName: string, args: any, gas: number, amount?: BN): Promise<**FinalExecutionOutcome**> {}

but when I try to get the result, it is always null.

The idea is to get transaction details from the response.

This is sample code

```
import * as nearAPI from "near-api-js"
import { getConfig } from './config'

async initContract() {

if (!this.contract) {
    //initialize near
    await this.initNear();

    this.contract = await this.near.loadContract(process.env.CONTRACT_NAME, { // eslint-disable-line require-atomic-updates
        // NOTE: This configuration only needed while NEAR is still in development
       
        viewMethods: [...],
        // Change methods can modify the state. But you don't receive the returned value when called.
        changeMethods: [ ...."set_comments"],
        // Sender is the account ID to initialize transactions.
        sender: ....
    });
}

return this;
}


    async setComments(
        id: String,
        comments: String
    ) {
        if (this.contract) {
           const respone=  await this.contract.set_comments(
                {
                    id: id,
                    comments: comments
                });
            return respone;
//response is always coming as null even though the comments are updated on near
        }
        return null;
 

       }
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you calling this from NodeJS or from a browser app? What version of near-api-js are you using?

Comment: Have you tried raw `functionCall` from `Account`, which is what a `Contract` changeMethod [uses internally](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/ca817850ff2faad426483835c779b32a84f5c979/src/contract.ts#L53)?

Comment: we are calling this NodeJS server application. We tried with both 0.27 and 0.38

Comment: const acc = await this.near.account(...);
const rawResult = await acc.functionCall(process.env.CONTRACT_NAME, "set_comments", {
               id: id,
               comments: comments
            });     Able to get the response using this way. Do we have always call the functions using this method

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `functionCall` method, you are using the method on the contract directly. If you want the transaction details, you need to use the `functionCall` method on the account, like the below example:

I assume you return `near` inside `initNear()`, and can connect to the wallet.

```ts
// initialize near
const near = await this.initNear();

// connect to the wallet
const wallet = new WalletConnection(near,'APP_KEY_PREFIX');


// Inside setComments function
const response = await wallet.account().functionCall({
  contractId: this.contract.contractId,
  methodName: 'set_comments',
  args: {
   id: id,
   comments: comments
  },
});
```